how to permanently change the color after the light hits the animation
I'm new to blender, so I need some advice. I would like to create a sheder that permanently changes color when a beam of light hits it.
I have created an animation where the object is rotating and the spotlights are static and I would like to change the color wherever the spotlight rays hit.
Thanks for your help.
I don't have any ideas. I've been playing around with shading, but it's getting nowhere.

This is off topic as it has nothing to do with programming.
